# Compile with JDK 13 and run with JRE 8

Tags: java

I compiled my program, but when i try to run it, i get this error :

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Lanceur has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the J    ava Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to "move" the JDK 13 all the way up in PATH, restarted my PC, but nothing changed. Here is a screenshot :

[image: environment variables]

I then tried to download JRE 13, but can't find it anywhere.

How can i do this ?
I can't update to JDK 14 or up, because i need something that was removed in these versions

Comment: Java 13 is no longer supported but the key is to compile your code to say it is compatible with Java 8.  How did you compile?

Comment: I compile with `javac MainClass.java`, and then try ti run with `java MainClass`. If Java 13 is no longer supoerted then for it to work i need a higher version right ? ( I can't but I'm just asking )

Comment: Use `javac -target 1.8 MainClass.java`. Read also about the `-source` parameter.

Comment: I get this error message : `warning: target release 1.8 conflicts with default source release 13`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're compiling without a build environment, you'll need to build with:

```
javac -target 1.8 -source 1.8 MainClass.java
```

Java versioning is confusing but stick with 13 until you get used to it.

Comment: I think `-release` is better than `-source` and `-target`.

Comment: For newer Java's you're right @dan1st.  The Java 8 `javac` didn't have the `release` command line argument and the target/source arguments are still supported.  A bit backward compatible I guess.

Comment: I mean he uses java 13 for compiling but I guess it makes no difference

Comment: Spot on and also very useful comment by @dan1st and response by you!